# Push data in mongodb use value from another field

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, field, push, insert-update

I use mongoose for push data(use a value from rank_num field) to a field like this:

```
ListM.findOneAndUpdate({userId: req.body.userId}, 
        [{
            $push: {
                listData: {
                    ...req.body.musicToAdd,
                    pos: "$rank_num"
                }
            }
        }])
```

And not work..., i dont know how to add value of another field in $push. Help me! thank you

Comment: Can you describe your db structure?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add one value into your array field, try this. (rank_num is field name and req.body.musicToAdd is a value to be pushed.)

```
ListM.findOneAndUpdate(
  { userId: req.body.userId },
  { $push: { "rank_num": req.body.musicToAdd} },
  { safe: true, new: true }
).then((res) => {
   console.log("updated result is", res);
}).catch((error) => {
   console.log("error is", error);
});
```

If you want to push array to array field, try this. (listData is field name and req.body.musicToAdd is array to pushed.

```
ListM.findById(req.body.userId).then((res) => {
   if (!res) return;
   res.listData.push(...req.body.musicToAdd);
   res.save();
   return true;
})
catch((error) => {
   console.log("error is", error);
});
```